# Как вывести элементы массива?

Tags: c++, массивы, вывод

Нужно сделать так, чтобы один раз выводился текст, а рядом выводились элементы массива. Например:

```
ввод
5
```

```
вывод
output of numbers: 56 53 2 87 76
```

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int main() 
{
            int N;
    
            cout << "size array:" << endl;
            cin >> N;
            if (N > 1 && N < 256) {
                
                int* arr = new int[N];

                bool alreadyThere;

                for (int j = 0; j < N;)
                {
                    alreadyThere = false;
                    int newRandomValue = rand() % 256;

                    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
                    {
                        if (arr[i] == newRandomValue)
                        {
                            alreadyThere = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!alreadyThere)
                    {
                        arr[j] = newRandomValue;
                        j++;
                    }
                }

  
                    cout << "output of numbers: " << arr[j];
               
            } 
            else {
                cout << "wrong number entered" << endl;
            }

            return 0;

    
}
```

Comment: Так уберите вывод текстового сообщения из цикла, оставив только вывод новоявленного элемента из массива.

Comment: он и так не в цикле

Comment: Ну, тогда вывод массива нужно поместить в цикл, как бы это странно не звучало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int main() 
{
            int N;
    
            cout << "size array:" << endl;
            cin >> N;
            if (N > 1 && N < 256) {
                
                int* arr = new int[N];

                bool alreadyThere;
                cout << "output of numbers: ";
                for (int j = 0; j < N;)
                {
                    alreadyThere = false;
                    int newRandomValue = rand() % 256;

                    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
                    {
                        if (arr[i] == newRandomValue)
                        {
                            alreadyThere = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!alreadyThere)
                    {
                        arr[j] = newRandomValue;
                        cout << " " << arr[j];
                        j++;
                    }                       
                }                                               
            } 
            else 
            {
                cout << "wrong number entered" << endl;
            }

            return 0;       
}
```

Просмотр онлайн в [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/xM1dI3)

Comment: спасибо огромное.

Answer (score -1):

Так годится?

```
unsigned int N;
cin >> N;
cout << "output of numbers: ";
for(;N-->0;) cout << rand() % 256 << " ";
cout << endl;
```

Comment: Нет фильтра дубляков. Можно сделать еще короче - автор просто изобрел плохой велосипед std::shuffle

Comment: @gbg Еще раз перечитал вопрос. Ничего о дубликатах в нем нет. Да, он спрашивает, как вывести массив, так что лучше было бы `for(;N-->0;) cout << a[N-1] << " ";`, но о дублях ничего в вопросе нет!

Comment: Ну да, а слона (в виде цикла имени Шлемиэля) в коде вы не заметили?

Comment: Я начинающий программист, поэтому и написал такую большую проверку